# Spark UDF - Task not serializable exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create UDF using the below scala code

```
lazy val formattedDF = df.withColumn("result_col", validateudf(df("id")))

val validateudf = udf((id: Int) => {

  if(id == 1){
     "ID IS EQUAL TO 1"
  } 
  else if(id > 1){
    validateId(id)
  }
  else{
    "NO VALID RECORDS"
  }
})

def validateId(id:Int) : String = {
   if (id > 2) {
     "ID IS GREATER THAN 2"
   }
   else {
     "VALID RECORDS"
   }
 }
```

When I run this code, I am getting task not serializable exception.

Any Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: We need more details about exception - stacktrace and etc

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
 at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
 at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)

Comment: Is it full code? It seems that you have some closure in your code. When you use UDF, you should be careful about closure.

Comment: Move your validateId method inside validateudf, it should help (if it's full code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`udf` is taken as a black box which requires the columns passed to be serialized and deserialized so use of `udf` is not recommended when you have alternatives with built-in functions.

Calling `udf` function with `withColumn` is fine but you have called another function `validateId` from inside the `udf` function which caused the issue.

I would suggest you not to use `udf` function at all as you can achieve the requirement just by using `when` built-in function.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val formattedDF2 = df.withColumn("result_col", when($"id" === 1, lit("ID IS EQUAL TO 1")).otherwise(when($"id" > 2, lit("ID IS GREATER THAN 2")).otherwise(when($"id" > 1, lit("VALID RECORDS")).otherwise(lit("NO VALID RECORDS")))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But i am planning to implement few other validations on id column inside validateId method.

Comment: @user7693124 you can add them to the when list :) thanks for the upvote and acceptance